# Objective C Socket Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sockets, network-programming

I am very new to objective c with XCode environment, I just want to ask the concepts and how is socket programming done in objective c. And please if you can assist me with its API, could you please include it..I am madly needing it now.

Video tutorials are more best if there is..
Please help me guys.. I really need it

Thanks,
Aldee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best socket I found is [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) and the [tutorial](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket)

Comment: Thanks Cyprian! I will take a look at it.. :D  I appreciate your help.. Keep in touch.. :D